# How to handle java call out result set data in Oracle Service Bus 11g?

Tags: java, oracle, xml-parsing, weblogic11g, osb

I have a java call out in a OSB service to run a simple select query from the database.the java code turns this result set into xml format and then returns this xml as string.but when ever i try to use this data in a transformation xquery it only shows the below in the response variable:

```
<con:java-content ref="jcid:2120886c:168088e4a35:-524c" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context"/> .
```

what i suspect is that the OSB is unable to handle the xml string.

code to convert result set into a xml string:

```
private static String toXML(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    StringBuffer xml = new StringBuffer();
    xml.append("<ns1:OutputCollection xmlns:ns1=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/namespace\">");

    while (rs.next()) {
        xml.append("<ns1:Output>");

        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
            String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            Object value = rs.getObject(i);
            xml.append("<ns1:" + columnName + ">");

            if (value != null) {
                xml.append(value.toString().trim());
            }
            xml.append("</ns1:" + columnName + ">");
        }
        xml.append("</ns1:Output>");
    }

    xml.append("</ns1:OutputCollection>");


    return xml.toString();

}
```

Comment: Please add code that transforms ResultSet into XML

Comment: edited the question and added the code.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13159_01/osb/docs10gr3/userguide/context.html#wp1106656.

OSB sees the return value as a reference to a java object. It doesn't know what a java string is or how to handle it. You will have to convert it to an XmlObject or let the java callout return an XmlObject.